# How can I use sensor data to affect the object in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, sensors, scenekit

I am implementing an `AR` app in iOS platform with `SceneKit`. I wanna my object to rotate followed by mobile rotation. For the mobile rotation side, I found there is a parameter called quaternion under `CMAttitude` class but I am not sure how can I use this parameter to rotate the object I loaded in the scene. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code. Show a screenshot. What do you want to see instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
if motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main, withHandler: { (devMotion, error) -> Void in
        //change the left camera node euler angle in x, y, z axis
        cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(
            -Float((devMotion?.attitude.roll)!) - Float(M_PI_2),
            Float((motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.yaw)!),
            -Float((motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.pitch)!)
        )
    })}
```

I tried this with Playground app in iPad.

Comment: let me follow your idea to try on the object.

Comment: Recently I tried and it will work as long as I figure out how to use update method in SceneKit (like Unity update method). Otherwise, the object won't move continuously.

Comment: Eventually I did self.arrow.orientation = SCNQuaternion(-CGFloat((motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.quaternion.x)!), -CGFloat((motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.quaternion.y)!), -CGFloat((motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.quaternion.z)!), CGFloat((motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.quaternion.w)!)) to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using Core Motion, but what I do is rotate the scnCamera

Comment: Actually I don't wanna rotate my camera, rotating the object is what I want. But would you mind telling me how you rotate your camera?